# Prove that the maximum total resistance of two parallel resistors is when the resistors are equal

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

Taking the two resistors as $x$ and $y$, I have to prove that resistance is maximum when $x = y$. The total resistance is given by $$R = \frac{xy}{x+y}\ $$

How can I solve for the general case, with no relation between x and y, using any branch of mathematics. That is, **why is it that for any y, the maximum total resistance will be when x = y**

Related but not duplicate: [Inequality for the combined resistance of two resistors connected in parallel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944693/inequality-for-the-combined-resistance-of-two-resistors-connected-in-parallel)

Comment: can you use $AM-GM$?

Comment: To use basic differentiation you rearrange the equation into terms of the ratio of $x$ to $y$ and differentiate with respect to that.  $R=x/y$. Find $df/dR$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x+y}$, $x\neq -y$

Then we must simultaneously solve $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0$ note that these are the partial derivatives of $f$

$\frac{\partial f }{ \partial y} = \frac{(x+y)\cdot x - xy}{(x+y)^2} = \frac{x^2}{(x+y)^2} $

Similarily, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{y^2}{(x+y)^2}$

Can you proceed from here?

Edit:

Then $$\frac{y^2}{(x+y)^2} =\frac{x^2}{(x+y)^2} = 0$$

$$y^2=x^2=0$$

$\implies y=\pm x$

But we have that $x\neq -y$, so $y=x$

so we're left with the stationary point $x=y=0$, but this implies that $x=-y$, hence there are no stationary points.

It is then not possible to conclude that $x=y$ provides the maximum with the given information.

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't learned partial derivatives yet, nor can it be used in the examination. However I'm very curious as to how an answer may be found through this method. Would you mind completing the solution?

Comment: Doesn't your proof imply that x=y=0? Hence they're both zero?

Comment: @VedantChandra I edited my answer.

Comment: Doesn't your answer still imply that x^2 and y^2 are both equal to zero, hence both are zero?

Comment: @VedantChandra No it doesn't, since the original function has $x\neq -y$, the point $(0,0)$ is not in the functions domain, and so isn't a stationary point

Answer (score 0):

**General case** (following EDIT):

The maximum total resistance is infinite, and this is achieved with $x=y=\infty$, i.e. two open circuits (or no circuit at all if you like).

Comment: @vedantchandra: maybe this will help you understand why another constraint is mandated.

Comment: You're right of course, but I'm not trying to find the maximum possible resistance. I'm asking a proof for why the total resistance is always maximised when x = y.

Comment: @VedantChandra: because $\infty=\infty$, maybe ?

Comment: It seems like the $x=y=\infty$ is a rather crude statement, the maximum as posed in the question is surely given by $(x\to\infty, y\to\infty)$ - but it remains to be proved that $x=y$

Comment: @mrnovice: all this discussion is a nonsense. In the unconstrained case, there is no maximum, full stop. This is what my answer wanted to show, but visibly it failed.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ∞=∞ in many cases, and there's plenty of proof out there for that.

Comment: I agree with @mrnovice 's comment. There's nothing wrong with your answer, it's just not what I'm looking for. Yes, the maxima is unbounded. But why is it that for any y, the maximum total resistance will be when x = y.

Comment: @VedantChandra: you continue to be blind. This statement is false.

Comment: @mrnovice: if you prefer, the minimum admittance is achieved when both admittances are zero, $x^{-1}=y^{-1}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

As argued above, if nothing is known about $x$ and $y$, other than that they are positive, there is no definite maximal value. However, the answer suggested may be obtained if it is assumed (not stated in the original problem, though) that the sum $x+y$ is fixed, say, $x+y=\varrho > 0$. Indeed, with this condition,
$$R=\frac{x(\varrho-x)}{\varrho} =-\frac{x^2}{\varrho}+x$$
and this quadratic is maximized when $x=-\frac{1}{2\cdot(-\frac{1}{\varrho})}=\tfrac{1}{2}\varrho$, and then also $y=\varrho -x = \tfrac{1}{2}\varrho$.

Comment: We could, in principle, assume many other constraints on $x$ and $y$. Given that the OP has not offered any other piece of information, though, why should we do it?

Comment: A bit like jeopardy: here is the answer, what was the question? Indeed, the problem (somewhat incomplete) came with an answer. What simple assumption could be missing?